# An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/register.html]")] with root cause

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem in my code, i don't know why my register page doesn't work, could someone help.

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        if (userService.getUserById(user.getIdUser()) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Email déjà utilisé.");
            return "register";
        }

        // Sauvegarder l'utilisateur dans la base de données
        userService.saveUser(user);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nom;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String prenom;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date date_inscription;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_activity",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id")
    )
    private List<Activity> activities;

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getDate_inscription() {
        return date_inscription;
    }

    public void setDate_inscription(Date date_inscription) {
        this.date_inscription = date_inscription;
    }

    public List<Activity> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(List<Activity> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inscription</title>
    <!-- Ajoutez des liens vers des bibliothèques CSS telles que Bootstrap pour améliorer le style de la page -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 2rem;
        }

        .form-container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-container">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-4">Inscription</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="nom" class="form-label">Nom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" th:field="*{nom}" placeholder="Nom" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="prenom" class="form-label">Prénom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" th:field="*{prenom}" placeholder="Prénom" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Adresse e-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Adresse e-mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">S'inscrire</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I put my html file in templates.
My error :
"An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/register.html]")] with root cause"

I think my error is due to this code :

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import java.security.SecureRandom;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/register")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> {
                    try {
                        form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true") // URL de redirection en cas d'échec
                                    .permitAll()
                                .and()
                                .logout()
                                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                                    .permitAll();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }


}
```

Comment: The stacktrace that comes with the error tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: We need a full stacktrace. I used your code as-is and the page built and presented without an error.

Comment: so where can be the error, maybe in mvcConfig ?

Comment: I need more info. I have requested proper stacktrace. Also enough code to reproduce the error.